# Rails View - How to escape special characters to include within a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, escaping

I am trying to escape special characters e.g. (space : / &) for inclusion into a link. I have tried the following but it will only escape '#' characters.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?text=<%=location.title.html_safe%><%=h root_url(:anchor => "_lat=#{location.latitude}&long=#{location.longitude}&zoom=17").html_safe%>">Tweet</a>
```

I have also tried `<%=CGI.escapeHTML location.title%><%=CGI.escapeHTML root_url(...)%>` it does not escape spaces or the http:// in root_url

Thanks.

**EDIT**
Thanks Sirupsen, here's up I ended up doing and the output is now correct except for white space is escaped as +, it works not sure if it is the best...

```
<!-- added var to make it more readable-->
<% tweetLink = root_url(:anchor => "_lat=#{location.latitude}&long=#{location.longitude}&zoom=17")%>
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?text=<%= URI.encode_www_form_component "#{location.title} #{tweetLink}"%>">Tweet</a>
```

Output is correct based on location.title ="http:// test in title":

https://twitter.com/share?text=http%3A%2F%2F+test+in+title+http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F%23_lat%3D43.82864423876971%26long%3D-79.36823174357414%26zoom%3D17 and twitter accepts it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Don't you just need simple URL escaping? `CGI.escape`

Comment: URI:scape(location.title) escapes spaces for me - can you show the link that you're getting?

Comment: @Sirupsen thanks, I dug deeper into the documentation.  Thanks for your inputs.